# Animate prefixed CSS rules in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to animate a `-webkit-transform` rule. I tried:

```
element.children().animate('webkitTransform': "translate3d(200px, 0, 0)", 200);
element.children().animate('WebkitTransform': "translate3d(200px, 0, 0)", 200);
element.children().animate('-webkit-transform': "translate3d(200px, 0, 0)", 200);
```

What am I missing?

Applying the CSS without animation works fine:

```
element.children().css('-webkit-transform', "translate3d(200px, 0, 0)");
```

Animate also works if I animate a non prefixed property like `margin-left`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is invalid Javascript. The first parameter needs to be an object. I still don't believe you can animate this property even with the right syntax.

```
element.children().animate({webkitTransform: "translate3d(200px, 0, 0)"}, 200);
```

This article may be able to help you out, though: http://cameronspear.com/blog/animating-translate3d-with-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

You can't animate this particular property since it is not numeric. Prefixes have nothing to do with that. From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality